# working with packages gets a module not found error

Tags: python, package, python-import

I want to re-structure my Python application that I had before in one directory, which works well.
Now I want to move some Python modules in packages, but I have problems with the import of the modules.

Say, this is my project folder:

```
project
   |
   |- package
   |      |- __init__.py
   |      |- module1.py
   |      |- module2.py
   |- main.py
```

with main.py:

```
from package.module1 import func1

func1()
```

module1.py:

```
from module2 import func2

def func1():
    func2()
```

module2.py:

```
def func2():
    pass
```

The file package/**init**.py is empty.

When I run main.py, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\wielando\Documents\Temp\pytest\main.py", line 1, in <module>     
    from packages.module1 import func1
  File "c:\Users\wielando\Documents\Temp\pytest\package\module1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module2 import func2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func2'
```

Why module2 is not found from module1 althought it is in the same folder?

Comment: try to replace `from module2 import func2` with `from package.module2 import func2` for python 2 or to `from .module2 import func2` for python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) for an explanation of absolute VS relative imports.

Anyway, you can either use a ***relative*** import:

module1.py

```
from .module2 import func2
```

(using the dot in front of module2 tells the program to look for module2 in the same folder).

Or, you can use an ***absolute*** import, i.e. by giving the full path of the file you are importing from the project’s root folder.
In your case, it would be:

module1.py

```
from my_packgs.module2 import func2
```

If you're using an IDE like PyCharm, you'll notice that in the case of absolute import, the instruction is marked as an error.
This is because the IDE doesn't know that the absolute path you provide in module1.py is using the folder where main.py is located as starting point (since you're executing main.py, the path where main.py is located is the project root folder). Anyway, when you run main.py, everything works.

Comment: Uuh, that was easy, thanks :-)
Is this the common way to use such "subpackages"?

Comment: No problem :)
I edited the answer to give you a better view of the whole thing.